# Better translation for "Grateful for everything life has given me"

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, difference, traditional-characters

Is "感谢对一切生活给予我" or "感谢生活所给予我的一切" a better translation for the proverb "Grateful for everything life has given me". If both don't make sense what is the accurate translation?

Comment: The 1st one doesn't make sense; the 2nd one is fine.

Comment: Also note that 給 is pronounced ji3 here.

Comment: 感激生命赐予我的一切, 感激上天赐予我的一切

Answer (score 3):

The second sentence is exactly what you are looking for.

The first sentence doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am grateful for everything which life has bestowed upon me.
我十分感激生活赐予我的一切。

Answer (score 0):

The latter is correct. The former doesn't make any sence.

One thing you should know is that **the position of an attribute（定语）is different between English and Chinese.** As we all know, in English if the attribute is only one word, it should be placed before the noun. When the attribute is more than one word or a sentence, it should be placed after the noun instead. **But in Chinese, no matter how long an attribute is, even it becomes a sentence, it showes before a noun forever.**

So the question becomes easy to understand."Greatful for everything" is the main of the sentence, which can be directly translated as "感激一切". And "life has given me" is the attribute (clause) to decorate the word "everything". So it should be place before "一切" like "生活所给予我的一切".

Answer (score 0):

感谢生活所给予我的一切 is better.
If you want to learn more, you can check here and study chinese with fun 
http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/chinese-immersion-course

Answer (score 0):

凡事感恩

凡事(Everything)感恩(Be grateful) > Be grateful for everything

This is not a direct translation but it's from Chinese Bible.

Everything includes "everything life has given me"

In your translation, you use "感谢"(Be thankful / Thanks). Which is fine. But thanks to whom?

感谢 is to someone.
感谢你 (Thank you).

So "感恩" grateful is somewhat more spiritual